# Want to use 2 column value as row key

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on Primefaces and using `p:dataTable`. I want to pass values from 2 columns as `rowKey`. I am currently doing:

```
<p:dataTable var="record" value="#{upshighlevel.upstclist1}" id="highLevelTable"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{upshighlevel.selectedOverView}" rowKey="#{upshighlevel.column1}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" 
                scrollWidth="100%" scrollHeight="150" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                            {RowsPerPageDropdown} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
                            {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})

">
```

Answer (score 2):

In your data model, add a method that generates a row key from two or more attributes (columns).

For example:

```
public class MyDataModel {
    public String getRowKey() {
        String o = (String) (((MyDataModel) this).getId() != null ? ((MyDataModel) this).getId() : this.hashCode());
        o = o.concat(((MyDataModel) this).getSecondAttribut() != null ? " " +((MyDataModel) this).getSecondAttribut().toString() : "");
        return o;
    }
}
```

This can be used with something like: `<p:dataTable rowKey="#{upshighlevel.getRowKey()}" .. >`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using two columns as rowkey by binding a data model which implements *org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel* (instead of using the rowkey attribute). This allows you to implement your own logic for the rowkey handling.

Example Implementation:

```
public class MyDataModel<T extends AbstractMyEntity> extends ListDataModel<T> implements SelectableDataModel<T>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyDataModel(List<T> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(T object) {
        return object.getId() != null ? object.getId() : object.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public T getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> list = (List<T>) getWrappedData();

        for (T o : list) {
            if (o.getId() != null ? o.getId().equals(Long.valueOf(rowKey)) : Integer.valueOf(rowKey).equals(o.hashCode())) {
                return o;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Part of a xhtml page:

```
<p:dataTable var="searchresult"
            value="#{bean.myDataModelInstance}"
            selection="#{bean.selectedEntry}">

            <p:column selectionMode="single" />

            <p:column headerText="#{msgs.nr}">
                <h:outputText value="#{searchresult.nr}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msgs.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{searchresult.name}" />
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Example Controllerbean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SearchBean {
    private MyDataModel<YourObject> myDataModelInstance;
    private YourObject selectedEntry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
        // Fill that list with Objects
        myDataModelInstance = new MyDataModel<YourObject>(list)
    }

    // The usual getter and setters
}
```